# iPhone vs. iPod Touch Software Development

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, ipod-touch, gyroscope

I'll be working on a project in the near future to develop a relatively simple Bluetooth/Gyroscope application. The customer doesn't seem to know whether they want this to work on the iPhone or the iPod Touch and I have no experience working with either of the two- so it's best to assume they'll want it to work identically regardless of device.

I'm getting mixed results in my searches, some are saying that the iPod Touch does have a bluetooth chip or gyroscope and others aren't mentioning it. I assume the version of the device will matter, but I'm not sure what generation I'll be dealing with.

Are there any differences that I'll need to be aware of if I begin development with only one of the two devices? Also, what are the most widely supported development tools; my experience is obviously quite limited in this domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good starting point is the [iOS Technology Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898)

The iPod Touch obviously lacks the phone capabilities and will more likely not have an active network connection as it only has WiFi. Bluetooth and Gyro will be there on both models (latest generation at least).

Comment: Yeah I'm finding tons of mixed results in searches as for when these features actually arose but it seems that 4th generation iPod Touch and iPhone 4 will have both. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Different versions of the iPod touch have different capabilities. For example, prior to rev 3 the touch didn't have a gyroscope.